# How can I add a CSS class to all the tables?

Tags: theming

I want to add a *table* class to all the tables, automatically. How can I achieve this by overriding a theme function?

Comment: Given the form requires an `_alter()` and this requires a `_preprocess()`, I think they both should stand; otherwise, I'm almost certain someone would complain about asking two questions at the same time.

Comment: Now there is just a missing question about adding a CSS class to a form element created with the FAPI, and we covered up all the cases. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

If your table is rendered using `theme('table')`, you can preprocess it from your theme function.

```
function my_theme_preprocess_table(&$variables) {
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'table';
}
```