# How to add wrapping elements & classes to a table in a view?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm building a custom theme using bootstrap 3, I need responsive tables. Yes, I'm aware of [responsive_tables](https://drupal.org/project/responsive_tables) but I didn't like it. I want to use bootstrap's native [`.table-responsive`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive). for that I need to wrap table like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

I need to add couple more classes to the `<table>` element.

How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a CSS class to all the tables?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100467/how-can-i-add-a-css-class-to-all-the-tables)

Comment: @Molot: Thanks for pointing the "possible" duplicate but main question is "How to add wrapper html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add css class to the whole view (go to your view edit page -> Advanced -> Other -> Css Class). It will print something like this:

```
<div class="view view-test view-id-test view-display-id-page table-responsive view-dom-id-47b9f610df77a3f6181e64ca36b9881e">
  <div class="view-content">
    <table class="views-table cols-2">
       ...
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

In views UI there is no option to add class to `<table>` element, but you can create/copy a template file (e.g. views-view-table.tpl.php, you can copy it from views module, look in "Theme information" in your view for more specific details) in your theme, clear caches and edit it as you wish.

Comment: Will `views-view-table.tpl.php` work? How did you arrive at this template file?

Comment: In you view edit page go to Advanced -> Other -> Theme: Information and you will see all the suggestions, what template files you can use for your view. After copy you need also to clear cache.

Comment: Adding the css the advanced->other-css class way did not work for me. It did not put it close enough to the table. It seems to be needed right in <div class="view-content"> area for it to work... ie  <div class="view-content table-responsive...

Comment: For convenience, the default place to find the base file to use for your template is `/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-table.tpl.php`