# Add class that surrounds all tables (or any other node,field etc...) using preprocess template?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have been able to find information on adding classes to tables and other items in my pages, however, I cannot find any information on wrapping the entire table for example in a div through the preprocess function.

I added this for example:

```
function bootstrap_preprocess_views_view_table(&$vars) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'table table-striped';
}
```

My tables are stripped which is what I was after, however, I would like to wrap the entire table itself in `<div class="table-responsive">{TABLE}</div>`, but am not finding where / how to add the class to show before the table?

Adding a picture of where it could be added:[image: table layout in code]

Comment: This post that helped out a little: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104960/how-to-add-wrapping-elements-classes-to-a-table-in-a-view. However, it is still not working due to the table-responsive being a couple divs up. Not sure why it worked for the OP there.

Answer (score 0):

you can override [views-view-table.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-table.tpl.php/7) template to achieve this.

Like :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table <?php if ($classes) { print 'class="'. $classes . '" '; } ?><?php print $attributes; ?>>
   <?php if (!empty($title) || !empty($caption)) : ?>
     <caption><?php print $caption . $title; ?></caption>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if (!empty($header)) : ?>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <?php foreach ($header as $field => $label): ?>
          <th <?php if ($header_classes[$field]) { print 'class="'. $header_classes[$field] . '" '; } ?>>
            <?php print $label; ?>
          </th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row_count => $row): ?>
      <tr <?php if ($row_classes[$row_count]) { print 'class="' . implode(' ', $row_classes[$row_count]) .'"';  } ?>>
        <?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>
          <td <?php if ($field_classes[$field][$row_count]) { print 'class="'. $field_classes[$field][$row_count] . '" '; } ?><?php print drupal_attributes($field_attributes[$field][$row_count]); ?>>
            <?php print $content; ?>
          </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Get a look for override views template [here](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/carmstrong/2013/02/27/quick-tutorial-overriding-drupal-views-using-templates)

For other tables Override [theme_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) and change its return statement Like:

```
return '<div class="table-responsive">'.$output.'</div>';
```